# Checking microphone volume in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to make a little game that needs access to the users mic. I need to be able to check if a mic is connected, and then if so, check the volume of the sound coming through the mic through the duration of the game. How would I do this?

Comment: The two original answers refer to a sample that no longer worked (for me), so I added a new answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50279260/1863152 that includes a mic vu meter with numeric and visual outputs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the snippet needed to detect audio controls are available (pulled from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia)

```
navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Here is a sample using the getUserMedia function that will enable you access to the microphone.

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                     navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } },
      function(stream) {
         console.log("Accessed the Microphone");
      },
      function(err) {
         console.log("The following error occured: " + err.name);
      }
    );
} else {
   console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
```

Here is a repository that demonstrates the "input volume" you desire.

https://github.com/cwilso/volume-meter/

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helped!

Comment: OP said `check the volume of the sound coming through the mic`. I don't see how this answer helps achieve that..

Comment: His original question is to see how the `mic is connected` then if connected `check the volume of the sound coming through the mic` to which I provided a repository that demonstrates that (to which you also provided).

Comment: It looks like this works in Firefox, but not Chrome (no volume-meter is drawn in Chrome).

Answer (score 78):

A slightly more detailed answer after having to work it out myself feel may help others looking here.

This following code will log out a number of approx 0 to 100 based on the microphone volume.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: true,
  video: true
})
  .then(function(stream) {
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    const microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    const scriptProcessor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);

    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.8;
    analyser.fftSize = 1024;

    microphone.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(scriptProcessor);
    scriptProcessor.connect(audioContext.destination);
    scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess = function() {
      const array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
      const arraySum = array.reduce((a, value) => a + value, 0);
      const average = arraySum / array.length;
      console.log(Math.round(average));
      // colorPids(average);
    };
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    /* handle the error */
    console.error(err);
  });
```

If you have this number jquery to style blocks of color. An example function of this i have provided below but that is the easy part. Just un-comment out the
color pids function.

```
function colorPids(vol) {
  const allPids = [...document.querySelectorAll('.pid')];
  const numberOfPidsToColor = Math.round(vol / 10);
  const pidsToColor = allPids.slice(0, numberOfPidsToColor);
  for (const pid of allPids) {
    pid.style.backgroundColor = "#e6e7e8";
  }
  for (const pid of pidsToColor) {
    // console.log(pid[i]);
    pid.style.backgroundColor = "#69ce2b";
  }
}
```

To make sure this answer is as detailed as possible i have also attached my html and css below so you can just copy the js html and css if you wish to get a working example up and running.

html:

```
<div class="pids-wrapper">
  <div class="pid"></div>
  <div class="pid"></div>
  <div class="pid"></div>
  <div class="pid"></div>
  <div class="pid"></div>
  <div class="pid"></div>
  <div class="pid"></div>
  <div class="pid"></div>
  <div class="pid"></div>
  <div class="pid"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.pids-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
}
.pid{
  width: calc(10% - 10px);
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

After all that you will end up with something like this.
[image]

Comment: The volume level goes over 100 sometimes higher than 200 using this code. Any idea how to get exactly between 0-100 ??

Comment: How to connect with specific audio device?

Comment: How to make it work for a particular device instead of default internal speakers?

Comment: Note that `createScriptProcessor` has been deprecated since 2014 in favor of `AudioWorklet`, it's be nice to see an updated example

Comment: @mrossman I've written an updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64650826/4180937) using `setTimeout` instead.

Comment: @mrossman here's the answer for `AudioWorklet` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62702721/how-to-get-microphone-volume-using-audioworklet

Answer (score 19):

Here is an answer simply using `setTimeout` instead of the deprecated `createScriptProcessor` function:

```js
(async () => {
  let volumeCallback = null;
  let volumeInterval = null;
  const volumeVisualizer = document.getElementById('volume-visualizer');
  const startButton = document.getElementById('start');
  const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');
  // Initialize
  try {
    const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: {
        echoCancellation: true
      }
    });
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    const audioSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioStream);
    const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = 512;
    analyser.minDecibels = -127;
    analyser.maxDecibels = 0;
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.4;
    audioSource.connect(analyser);
    const volumes = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    volumeCallback = () => {
      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(volumes);
      let volumeSum = 0;
      for(const volume of volumes)
        volumeSum += volume;
      const averageVolume = volumeSum / volumes.length;
      // Value range: 127 = analyser.maxDecibels - analyser.minDecibels;
      volumeVisualizer.style.setProperty('--volume', (averageVolume * 100 / 127) + '%');
    };
  } catch(e) {
    console.error('Failed to initialize volume visualizer, simulating instead...', e);
    // Simulation
    //TODO remove in production!
    let lastVolume = 50;
    volumeCallback = () => {
      const volume = Math.min(Math.max(Math.random() * 100, 0.8 * lastVolume), 1.2 * lastVolume);
      lastVolume = volume;
      volumeVisualizer.style.setProperty('--volume', volume + '%');
    };
  }
  // Use
  startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Updating every 100ms (should be same as CSS transition speed)
    if(volumeCallback !== null && volumeInterval === null)
      volumeInterval = setInterval(volumeCallback, 100);
  });
  stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(volumeInterval !== null) {
      clearInterval(volumeInterval);
      volumeInterval = null;
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
div {
  --volume: 0%;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

div::before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: var(--volume);
   background-color: green;
   transition: width 100ms linear;
}

button {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h3><b>NOTE:</b> This is not accurate on stackoverflow, since microphone use is not permitted. It's a simulation instead.</h3>
<div id="volume-visualizer"></div>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

This also means, that it can easily be started and stopped on demand.

Comment: Hey there! just stumbled upon your answer. I was looking for an answer which didn't include  `createScriptProcessor`. But I have not understood why is minDecibels and maxDecibels and the calculation of averageVolume i.e. (averageVolume * 100 / 127). What does this inidicate. Anyone who understands this code please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @ShaileshB `averageVolume` is just the average of `volumes`. To get the percentage used to display the loudness, the `averageVolume` needs to be divided by the maximum possible value (offset). To determine that you need to subtract the minimum possible value (raw) `minDecibels` from the maximum possible value (raw) `maxDecibels`. Note that all volumes are offsets of `minDecibels`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you chose `127` as the maximum possible value for loudness?

Comment: @PeterToth Honestly no, but you can refer to the `AnalyserNode` documentation for [`getByteFrequencyData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData), [`minDecibels`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/minDecibels) and [`maxDecibels`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/maxDecibels) to choose values that work for you.

Answer (score 5):

Simple Microphone Vu Meter See https://codepen.io/www-0av-com/pen/jxzxEX

Checked and working in 2018, including bug fix caused by security update in Chrome browser.

HTML
    `<h3>VU meter from mic input (getUserMedia API)</h3>
    <button onclick="startr();" title="click start needed as security in browser increased and voice mic can only be started from a gesture on page">Start</button>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="300" style='background:blue'></canvas>
    <br>
    CLICK START
    <div align=left>See JS for attribution</div>`

CSS

```
body {
  color: #888;
  background: #262626;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#canvas {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 45%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS (needs JQuery)

```
// Courtesy www/0AV.com, LGPL license or as set by forked host, Travis Holliday, https://codepen.io/travisholliday/pen/gyaJk 
function startr(){
 console.log ("starting...");
 navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
   navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
 if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.getUserMedia({
      audio: true
    },
    function(stream) {
      audioContext = new AudioContext();
      analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
      microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      javascriptNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);

      analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.8;
      analyser.fftSize = 1024;

      microphone.connect(analyser);
      analyser.connect(javascriptNode);
      javascriptNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

      canvasContext = $("#canvas")[0].getContext("2d");

      javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {
          var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
          analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
          var values = 0;

          var length = array.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            values += (array[i]);
          }

          var average = values / length;

//          console.log(Math.round(average - 40));

          canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, 150, 300);
          canvasContext.fillStyle = '#BadA55';
          canvasContext.fillRect(0, 300 - average, 150, 300);
          canvasContext.fillStyle = '#262626';
          canvasContext.font = "48px impact";
          canvasContext.fillText(Math.round(average - 40), -2, 300);
          // console.log (average);
        } // end fn stream
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log("The following error occured: " + err.name)
    });
} else {
  console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
 }
}
```

Comment: any idea how to make it work on safari? or why it doesn't?

Comment: @Ann, at a guess I'd say it is because it's dealing with I/O that is completely different on the different OS's. Eg: Linux is usually run on hardware that is MS compatible, so I imagine this works in Chrome style browsers under MS or Linux, but Apple has completely different hardware. Sadly I have no time to research it (besides, you didn't mention if it is iPhone/iPad or Mac), but I would start with googling "audioContext.createMediaStreamSource not working on safari" .. that immediately confirmed you are not alone for me.

Comment: @Ann For Safari instead of `audioContext = new AudioContext();` do `audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();`