# How can I get the microphone volume in Angular?

Tags: angular, microphone

Is there any example to get the volume of the microphone in an Angular app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking microphone volume in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322681/checking-microphone-volume-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

you can get or set the microphone volume using the [Web Audio Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). This is completely unrelated to Angular.